# Youtube data api only returning json with a few number of videos

Tags: android, json, api, video, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube data api v3 to fetch youtube videos; data and by arsing the json it only gives me a few videos data.
Here is the URL I am using ->
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=science&key=mykey

I am getting only 5-7 videos data. But I want the complete large list of related YouTube videos to my call.

Any help how can I get the bigger amount of data in return to the API call
?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: post your code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should indicate the `maxResults` parameter:

> maxResults unsigned integer
>   The maxResults parameter specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set. Acceptable values are 0 to 50, inclusive. The default value is 5.